# Unity Top Down 2D Moving a object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, push, game-physics

I'm making a game and I want to push an object but I cant find out how to do it.

The player and the box have a rigibody2D and a box collider2d but it wont work, please help.

This is my script for the player but I couldn't move the object.

If you know how it works or you know a document that can help me, I would really appreciate.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
using Unity.Netcode;

public class PlayerController : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 1f;
    public float collisionOffset = 0.05f;
    public ContactFilter2D movementFilter;
    Vector2 movementInput;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    List<RaycastHit2D> castCollisions = new List<RaycastHit2D>();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start(){
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
   
    void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D colExt){
        if (colExt.gameObject.tag == "box")
        colExt.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = 
        Vector3.zero;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate() {
        if (!IsOwner) return;

        if(movementInput != Vector2.zero){
            bool success = TryMove(movementInput);

            if(!success) {
                success = TryMove(new Vector2(movementInput.x, 0));

                    if(!success){
                        success = TryMove(new Vector2(0, movementInput.y));
                    }
            }

        }
    }

    private bool TryMove(Vector2 direction) {
        int count = rb.Cast(
                direction,
                movementFilter,
                castCollisions,
                moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime + collisionOffset);
                
        if(count == 0){
            rb.MovePosition(rb.position + direction * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    void OnMove(InputValue movementValue) {
        movementInput = movementValue.Get<Vector2>();
    }

}
```

I tried different code from youtube or the internet but I did not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

This is very confusing but have you tried to simplify the code?

```cs
    public float moveSpeed = 1f;
    Vector2 movementInput;
    Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
   
    //I assume this is to stop moving the box but I didnt find when to start moving the box
    void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D colExt)
    {
        if (colExt.CompareTag("box"))
        colExt.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = 
        Vector3.zero;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate() 
    {
        if(movementInput != Vector2.zero)
        {
            bool success = TryMove(movementInput);
        }
    }

    void _Move(Vector2 direction) 
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + direction * moveSpeed * time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }

    void OnMove(InputValue movementValue)
    {
        movementInput = movementValue.Get<Vector2>();
    }
}
// Not tested
```

I tried to remove the unnecessary code for pushing "the box", now I didn't find an attempt to push the box, try adding something like the following:

```cs
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
  if (other.CompareTag("Box"))
  {
     other.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector3.up;
  }
}
// Not tested
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html

Comment: Thx for the help but i found the problem the movement script from player was the cause of not working fine thx for the help